# How to make rsync show system time after each file transfer?

Tags: rsync

Verbose option allows me to see each file that is transferred, I use options like `--stats` and `--info=progress2` to show me some more information on transfer process.

I want to figure out how to show system time after each file transfer, because sometimes when rsync fails because of tunnel failure, it freezes without notice and it looks like it is still transferring - process is not killed, but if system time would be shown on the screen, not only I could try debugging the problem easily, but also I would notice that something is wrong just by seeing timestamps on the shell screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From man pages: *--out-format=FORMAT     output updates using the specified FORMAT*

To show output on the screen, not in the log, I found `--out-format="%t %f"` to be working to my satisfaction.

---

lemonslice's first suggestion `--log-file` also outputted everything in the desired format, it looks like undocumented alias of `--out-format`, however `--log-file-format` does not show on the screen, it is an option for `--log-file`.

Answer (score 2):

The manual page of rsync tells that you can customize the log format. The `%t` tag means the current system date-time. For instance you can add the following switch to rsync:

> --log-file-format="%t [%p] %o %h [%a] %m (%u) %f %l"

More information in the manual pages
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/rsync.1.html (`log-file-format`) and
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/rsyncd.conf.5.html (log formatting tags).

Comment: the option seems to be `--log-file-format=...`